# Wrapfigure side by side on two columns

Tags: floats, positioning, minipage, wrapfigure

I need to insert two figures such that the figures would be side by side, starting from the left column and the second figure partially spanned on the next column. I've tried both wrapfig and minipage with no luck. Example of the requested layout:[image: example of the requested layout]

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

If you make a `figure` at the top of the left column and put in contents (pictures) that is too wide they will expand into the right column. Then you can use e.g. `wrapfig` in the right column to make space for the extra width. It will robably be a bit tricky to start the `wrapfigure` at the top of the right column. Here I have not put any effort at ending the left column in a nice way, I just made a `\newpage` when I could not fit another paragraph.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\begin{document}
\title{My title}
\author{Me}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-4]%% On left column second page

\begin{figure}[t]%% Put a picture that is too wide. It will continue in to the right column
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.7\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{First picture}
    \label{fig:first}
  \end{minipage}\rule{1em}{0pt}%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.7\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{Second picture}
    \label{fig:second}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1]%% Now at the bottom of left column on second page

\newpage %% On top of right column
\begin{wrapfigure}{L}{0.45\linewidth}%% Make room for the too wide figure in the left column
  \rule{0pt}{15em}% height of wrapfigure
\end{wrapfigure}

\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

[image]

As a note, I am not sure I would recommend this. If you have two fiugures that are too wide to put in one column I would either put them in seprate figures after each other or in on that spans both columns, e.g.

```
\begin{figure*}[t]
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.47\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{First picture}
    \label{fig:first}
  \end{minipage}\hfill%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.47\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{Second picture}
    \label{fig:second}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure*}
```

Comment: what if my images doesn't show in the start of the page? eliminating the \newpage yields a wrong layout.

Comment: @GuyCohen That is why it is at the top of page. There is no automatic alignment between the figure and wrapfigure so it is easier to do that way. You can of course put it anywhere but the positioning of the wrapfigure becomes harder.